# JavaScript Date() behaving strange, any ideas what's going wrong?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I've been trying to get a few dates to parse, but for some reason they keep rolling over to the next month - when they shouldn't.

Take this scenario for instance:

```
In January there are 31 days.
```

So why then does this happen:

```
var myDate = new Date(2013, 01, 31);
myDate.toDateString(); // output: "Sun Mar 03 2013"
```

Am I missing something with the `Date(year, month, day)` constructor?

Comment: I've looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date but there aren't any examples of how it is supposed to be constructed :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript's `Date` constructor, January is month 0, February is 1, ... December is 11.

Why is that?

The reason typically cited is that one can easily convert the month number back into the month name via an array lookup:

```
var months = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];
```

Then `'January' === months[0]`.

The problem then becomes remembering which languages follow which conventions :)

Comment: Common trap for new players. :-)

Comment: I really should of clocked onto that sooner! I've been doing this for a while now, I'm going to go and hang my head in shame! Cheers @Matt!

Comment: @JamieShanikwaStreet Don't worry I still get bitten by this one every so often :)